# Count the number of subcategories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I need to count number of child categories in Wordpress but i can not deal with it. Somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can count all the categories and subtract parent categories from them to get the child categories.

```
$total_categories_count  = wp_count_terms('category');
$parent_categories_count = count(get_categories('parent=0&hide_empty=0'));
$child_categories_count  = $total_categories_count - $parent_categories_count;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

mysql directly:

you should try something like:

```
SELECT categoria.id AS id_categoria, categoria.nome AS nome_categoria,
        subcategoria.id AS id_subcategoria, subcategoria.nome AS nome_subcategoria
            FROM categoria
            INNER JOIN subcategoria
            ON categoria.id = subcategoria.id_categoria
            ORDER BY nome_categoria, nome_subcategoria
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('parent' => YOUR_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID_NUMBER);
$categories_cnt = count(get_categories( $args ));

echo 'There are '. $categories_cnt .' subcategories in this category';
```

Is that what you were looking for?